# Table with set of 3 columns maximum which have same meaning

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have table `Person` which have maximum 3 `opinion` and for each rows of `Person` we have different opinion, in other word you never find 2 person that have the same opinion, there is **no many-to-many** relationship between `person` and `opinion`.

I will never check `opinion` for validation like no 2 person have same opinion, it's just for information.

the question it is :

should i make just one table

```
Person ( #id_person , ... , opinion1 , opinion2 , opinion3 , ... )
```

or add a new table :

```
Person ( #id_person , ... )

opinions ( #id_opinion , opinion , *id_person* ) // id_person FK
```

For me i don't want to create a new table `opinions` because it will have no meaning i will always add a new rows as much i have a new `Person`

also if i group  them in one table and i have just one `opinion` there will be problem of waste of space ? even if i declare `opinion` as `varchar` ?

And if i create a new table `opinions` it will need a primary pseudo-key `id_opinion` ?

a `opinion` can be a `varchar(50)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend two tables.  The first table is the `persons` table.  This would have a `PersonId` and all sorts of other information about the person.

The second table would be the `PersonOpinions` table.  This would have one row per opinion, with information such as:

- PersonId
- Opinion
- Date and time of the opinion
- Topic of the opinion (if appropriate)
- Method for inputing the opinion (if appropriate)

From what you say, there is no need for a separate `opinions` table, because the opinion is basically "unique".  However, you probably do want to store the opinions themselves in a separate table, which a separate row per opinion.

You can use a trigger to enforce the constraint that a person only has three opinions.  If you decide to change this in the future, then it will be easy with a two-table solution.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff for the answer but the informations you mention in table `PersonOpinions` will not be needed in my case at all. i need just only `opinion`, also for the constraint that a person only has three opinions i control it with javascript. i'm just afraid in the future in i will need more than 3 opinion but i will add a new colomn wich will be simpler, is not ?

Comment: @user3756879 . . . You should use a separate table rather than modifying an existing table.  One small reason is performance.  Presumably opinions can be big, so they don't need to be stored with all the other data about a person.  And to be honest, it is hard for me to imagine an application where the order of the opinions and the dates they were provided are not relevant, even in some tiny way.

Comment: what's the problem if they are big and i stored them with all the other data about a person ? if i create a new table i will store them also and make join to get them.

Comment: @user3756879 . . . First, it is more convenient to have them in one column.  For instance, if you create a full text index, you only have to do that one one column.  Second, if the opinions are big and you are running non-opinion queries on the `Persons` table, then having to read the opinions will slow down those queries.  If they are in a second table, non-opinions queries will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for 3 different tables(2 base and 1 intersection). Since Person and Opinions are 2 different entities and they might share a relationship of M:M so hence the need  of intersection table. I believe it will simply things instead of clutering the info in 1 single table.

Comment: no if you read my question i will never have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: in other word you never find 2 person that have the same opinion <- Yes, then it will be a 1:1. Still i would say making another table would be a better option. It will be easier to check if we need a validation like no 2 person have same opinion among other benefits of mantainability.

Comment: I said a person can have 3 opinion max so it's one-to-many relationship. and i will never check opinion for validation it's just for information.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two tables. (Whether you want opinion ids is a separate issue. You wouldn't need to.)

```
// person [id_person] has name [name] and ...
person(id_person,name,...)

// person [id_person] has opinion [opinion]
opinion(id_person,opinion)
    fk (id_person) references person
```

Your design is bad partly because: it is not clear what the answers to the following questions are, yet the answers must be known for someone to use the database. When you have given the answers (ie the rest of a full design of your table) they will illustrate other problems.

Suppose:

```
person p1 has opinion o11.
person p1 has opinion o12.
person p1 has no other opinions.
person p3 has opinion o21
person p3 has no other opinions.
```

A. What row(s) go in the table?

B. What are queries (without knowing the table value) for rows where

1. person p has opinion [opinion]
2. person [person] does not have opinion o

C. Every table needs a statement parameterized by its columns where the rows in the table are the rows that make the statement true.

1. What is the statement for your table?
2. Why *isn't* it

   ```
       person [id_person] is named [name] and ...
   AND person [id_person] holds opinion [opinion1]
   AND person [id_person] holds opinion [opinion2]
   AND person [id_person] holds opinion [opinion3]
   ...
   ```

You should experience the further badness in answering the questions. Besides being unclear, the desription so far is also bad because the answers are ugly and your table is difficult to use. So much so that I don't even want to type examples of what I know they will be like. So I will leave the questions rhetorical rather than with examples until you give more info.